# How to assertion automation selenium to compare json only on key without value

Tags: api, selenium, automation, cucumber, objectmapper

Wants to compare that both 2 endpoint have same keys even the values are different.

Response on endpoint A

```
{"name":"Anna", "age":20}
```

Response on endpoint B

```
{"name":"Anna", "age":null}
```

For now I tried using objectmapper like this, it can't

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ResponseApi<AResponse> aResponse = aController.getA();
ResponseApi<BResponse> bResponse = bController.getB();

String aReadResponse = String.valueOf(mapper.readTree(String.valueOf(aResponse)));
String bReadResponse = String.valueOf(mapper.readTree(String.valueOf(bResponse)));

assertEquals(mapper.readTree(aReadResponse), mapper.readTree(bReadResponse));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it can't" what? do you want to check if the keys of the responses are equal? can you show the import statements or specify which framework is used to convert the strings to JSON? is there maybe a `keys` or `keySet` property which you could use for `assertEquals`.

Comment: What is `ObjectMapper`? I mean can you give us a fully qualified name of this class?

Comment: Also what are `AResponse` a `BRsponse`?